Azure Devops Treat Warnings as Errors using DotNetCoreCLI@2
How to treat warnings as errors in Azure DevOps Pipeline VSBuild task? shows how to enable this when using VSBuild@1
Looking for how to implement via:
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: dotnet publish
    inputs:
      command: publish
      arguments: '--property:PublishDir=$(Build.BinariesDirectory) --self-contained true'
      configuration: $(BuildConfiguration)
      projects: $(Solution)
      modifyOutputPath: true
      publishWebProjects: true
      zipAfterPublish: false


While the input is not directly defined for DotNetCoreCLI@2
You can add:
--property:WarningAsError=true
to your list of arguments.
I found the list of valid properties for arguments here:
MS Build command-line reference
And it linked me here:
Common MS Build properties list
